# Unable to activate activemodel-3.2.15, because activesupport-4.0.1 conflicts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, rspec

Getting this error when trying to run my rspec tests (any or all):

```
Unable to activate activemodel-3.2.15, because activesupport-4.0.1 conflicts 
with activesupport (= 3.2.15), builder-3.1.4 conflicts with builder (~> 3.0.0)
```

My Gemfile has:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
rails_version = '~> 4.0.0.rc2'
gem 'activerecord', rails_version
gem 'actionpack',   rails_version
gem 'rspec', '~> 2.6.0'
gem 'mocha', '~> 0.9.8'
gem 'mongoid', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'
group :mysql do
  gem 'mysql', '~> 2.9'
  gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.10'
end
gem 'pg', '~> 0.11', :group => :pg
group :development do
  gem 'ruby-debug', :platforms => :mri_18
  gem 'debugger', :platforms => :mri_19
end
```

Not sure what to change/how to fix.

I tried:

- different rails version - `4.0.0` and `3.2.8`
- requiring 'activemodel' instead of activerecord and actionpack

and bundling after each but neither helped.

Ruby Version is `1.9.3-p194`

I tried ruby 2.0 but that gives errors about `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

I think the problem is about Mongoid.

The test code start like this:

```
before(:all) do
  MongoidModel.delete_all
  4.times { MongoidModel.create! }
end

let(:criteria) { MongoidModel.criteria }

describe "#page" do
  it "should forward to the paginate method" do
    expect(criteria(:paginate).with(:page => 2)).to returns("itself")
    expect(criteria.page(2)).to eq "itself"
  end
```

I has added Mongoid to the Gemfile.  The problem might be its version being not compatible with ruby 2 or rails 4, not sure and attempts to resolve have been unsuccessful.

I tried the moped gem and `bundle`d but then got `cannot load such file -- mongoid`

I tried gem 'mongoid', github: 'mongoid/mongoid' and `bundle`d but got the same error as trying moped.

Comment: How are you executing your tests? Are you using `bundle exec ...`? Do you have multiple versions of these gems installed? What happens if you empty out your gemset (or otherwise start with a fresh set of gems)?

Answer (score 2):

Your project wants to use Rails 3.x, but you have a Rails 4.x installed on your system.

That is fine, but you want to execute as:

```
bundle exec rake spec
```

To make sure you activate gem versions specified by your project, rather than the most recent versions installed on your system.

It might tell you that you need to run `bundle install` first to install all the gem versions specified by your project.